# Dell Precision 5570 codename

Tags: dell, software-sources, oem

Can someone with Dell Precision 5570 show here the /etc/apt/* coming on a Dell Precision with Ubuntu factory installed.

I'd like to know what specific repos I need to enable from http://dell.archive.canonical.com/dists/

Dell doesn't document that, and one has access to the original iso, only if he knows the right service tag.

So I don´t ask for any service tag, I just need to know what are the repos I have to enable.